# Setting Up My Own Exchange 2003 Server

Tags: exchange-2003, pop3

What I have is my emails being hosted through an email provider - Crazy Domains. At the moment I am just popping the emails down to my outlook client on 1 computer.

I would like to learn more about MS Exchange 2003. What I have build is a Windows 2003 Server, and I would like to set it up for my learning, to install Exchange Server 2003 (I have a copy of it already), and how I go about setting it up so that I can use Exchange on my local network for emails.

Eventually I plan on setting up Terminal Services as well on the server.

Thanks for your guidence.

Comment: Why the heck do you deal with REALLY outdated technology? 2003 is not "last generation" of exchange, it is TWO generations behind (like your windows OS). I suggest you move up to 2010 / 2008 R2 NOW ;)

Comment: I want to start at the 'beginning' so to speak.

Comment: @TomTom - if Newbie already has Exchange 2003 and Server 2003, it is a starting point and it doesn't cost anything. We're moving from Exchange 2003 to Exchange 2010 and the learning curve isn't *that* steep. Sure, some fundamentals have changed, but nothing that will totally blow your mind. If you understand Exchange 2003, you won't have too much of a hard time understanding Exchange 2010.

Comment: Okay, the issues that others have pointed out aside... what do you want to know?

Comment: A LOT has changed, including the complete admin interface. I know from training experience that quite a lot of Exchange 2003 admins get lost at 2010.

Comment: REAL men install Exchange 4.0 or Windows Messaging and upgrade to each subsequent version to learn.  That's how we did it when I was young dagnabit.  Damn kids!  GET OFF MY LAWN..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't really ask a question, BUT, I applaud you wanting to install this on your own network to learn.  This kind of experience counts for a LOT more toward employment than any certifications you can dream up and this is coming from someone in a position to hire employees.

It's not going to really matter whether you know Exchange 2003 like the back of your hand, or had a week's worth of training on Exchange 2010.  The assumption I would make is that if you know Exchange 2003 like the back of your hand, this speaks volumes about your ability to manage ANY Exchange environment.

My advice to you is to pick up a good book on Exchange 2003 (any of the ones put out by Microsoft Press are great starting points) and hack away at Exchange.  I would not follow the advice of Oskar (no offense) since SBS tends to take you out of the nuts and bolts of a lot of things and will keep your learning at an uncomfortable distance...

**Edited to add:**  I used to have quite a few blogs and websites bookmarked when my primary job was Exchange admin.  I'm trying to drum them up as I remember them and will list them below.

- [Jim McBee's Mostly Exchange Blog](http://mostlyexchange.blogspot.com/)
- [MS Exchange](http://www.msexchange.org/) (unfortunate domain name)

Comment: Thank you for your help with this. Yes, clearly I don't know what I'm doing - yet, but I plan on trying to build up some knoweldge to get me out of my deadend job and hopefully into some IT based career prospects.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't ask any question (yet :) ) but as you want to start from the beginning, I think you need some install guides like:

[microsoft technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123643%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx)
or
[here](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/exchange2003/exchange_2003_install.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the latest version (or the beta of the next version) of [SBS](http://www.microsoft.com/sbs/en/us/beta.aspx) instead, it will take care of most setup for you and generally offer Terminal Services by default as well.